# PostgreSQL view used in django (with managed=False) doesn't sync properly

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I need to use a database view (using Postgres) in my django application (version 1.6). Process was following:

1. I've created a view and then run `python manage.py inspectdb` to get proper model representation.
2. I've altered the model to reflect this situation.

Here's the code for view (it does work):

```
SELECT employee.employee_id, employee.firstname, employee.lastname, employee.birthdate, employee.is_active
FROM dblink( blah blah);
```

Here's the generated code for django model:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    employee_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    firstname = models.TextField(blank=True)
    lastname = models.TextField(blank=True)
    birthdate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.NullBooleanField()
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'employee'
```

I've experimented with using just `managed` (and not using `db_table`) or using both.

Anyway if i go syncdb i get such an error:

`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: referenced relation "employee" is not a table`

Ok, it's true but what the hell i am supposed to do with that?

I've also played with migration, but i'm getting some errors too:

`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "dblink_test2_employee" does not exist`

Any help appreciated? Am I overlooking something very clear to you?

Comment: I don't know django, but it appears you are trying to update a view, not a table.

Comment: Well, that's the way it should work. You create a view and then you tell django not to change it anyway by using `managed = False`

Answer (score 0):

make a new empty db on a separate machine.
pull the code with new models.py generated from inspectdb in a temporary new app (created with **startapp**)
then run makemigrations.
this will create the initial migration file in the migrations directory of the temporary app.

This is your initial migration file.

Copy this to your local machine.

Comment: also the name of the new db will be same as that of legacy one.
(In case of routing multiple dbs)